# ActiveRecord #collection method is not returning all collection that is saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, activerecord

I have User and Post objects. User has many posts and Post belongs to a User. Database adapter is sqlite3. My struggle is when I instantiate first new Post, save it and assign its user to instance of a User which is saved to database as well, everything works fine. However when I create a second post and assign its user to the same User, the user collection is returning an array that has only first post instance in it. When I checked database both of posts' user_id are same. Returning only first post does not make sense to me, while there are 2 posts in database with same user_id. Here is the codes.
( I am aware of user1.posts.create(text: "new post") would do what I want but I want to know what is the problem with #collection)

```rb
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
end

#post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

#schema.rb
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "text"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end
```

Comment: Please do not link to images with code or console output. Instead, copy and paste the relevant parts into your question. Images are hard to read, cannot be indexed and searched and people who want to help you have to transcribe your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run "user.posts" first time sql query loads from database all posts with this user. But when you run "user.posts" second time no sql query executed (for performance reasons) so you get only one post. Use "user.posts.reload" to reload posts (new query will be executed)